# Why calling printf result in a different function prologue for main?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, assembly, x86

When I compile

```
#include <stdio.h>
int
main () {
    return 0;
}
```

to x86 assembly the result is plain and expected:

```
$> cc -m32 -S main.c -o -|sed -r "/\s*\./d"
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    movl    $0, %eax
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

But when studying different disassembled binaries, the function prologue is never that simple. Indeed, changing the C source above into

```
#include <stdio.h>
int
main () {
    printf("Hi");
    return 0;
}
```

the result is

```
$> cc -m32 -S main.c -o -|sed -r "/\s*\./d"
main:
    leal    4(%esp), %ecx
    andl    $-16, %esp
    pushl   -4(%ecx)
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    pushl   %ecx
    subl    $4, %esp
    subl    $12, %esp
    call    printf
    addl    $16, %esp
    movl    $0, %eax
    movl    -4(%ebp), %ecx
    leave
    leal    -4(%ecx), %esp
    ret
```

In particular, I don't get why these instructions

```
leal    4(%esp), %ecx
andl    $-16, %esp
pushl   -4(%ecx)
```

are generated -- specifically why not directly storing `%esp` into `%ecx`, instead of into`%esp+4`?

Comment: Without optimization, compilers can produce a lot of trash. More than your examples, the double `subl` is a good hint for this bad behaviour.

Comment: Here is a good explanation:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228261/understanding-the-purpose-of-some-assembly-statements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `main` isn't a leaf function, it needs to align the stack for the benefit of any functions it calls.  Functions that aren't called `main` just maintain the stack's alignment.

```
lea 4(%esp), %ecx   # ecx = esp+4
andl    $-16, %esp
pushl   -4(%ecx)    # load from ecx-4 and push that
```

It's pushing a copy of the return address, so it will be in the right place after aligning the stack.  You're right, a different sequence would be more sensible:

```
mov    (%esp), %ecx   ; or maybe even  pop %ecx
andl   $-16, %esp
push   %ecx           ; push (mem) is slower than push reg
```

As Youka says in comments, don't expect code from `-O0` to be optimized *at all*.  Use `-Og` for optimizations that don't interfere with debugability.  The gcc manual recommends that for compile/debug/edit cycles.  `-O0` output is harder to read / understand / learn from than optimized code.  It's easier to map back to the source, but it's terrible code.